# C# How get Value of item (object) of ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, arraylist, foreach

Please help me, I am already stucked, to get the value (object) item of array list. which my array list filled from query . And the query result is in entity framework 6.0 .ToList() function . thank you very much for your help

```
private List<Documents> getDocOwn(string sortOrder, string searchStringName, string searchStringDept)
    {
        try
        {
            DocumentOwnerMapper objDocOwnMapper = new DocumentOwnerMapper();
            var listDocOwn = objDocOwnMapper.getList(sortOrder, searchStringName, searchStringDept);
            var listDocOwnModel = new List<M_DC_DocumentOwnerModel>();
            foreach (var obj in listDocOwn)
            {
               //how i can get the value of obj [dept] / obj[Name]
            }
            return new List<Document>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<Document>();
        }
    }
```

and here my public class for querying into database

```
public ArrayList getList(string strSortOrder, string strSeacrhStringName, string strSearchDept)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Entities ent = new Entities ())
            {
                ArrayList arrObj = new ArrayList();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSortOrder))
                {
                                                    var listObjName = ent.DocumentOwner.Join
                                 (ent.Employee.Where(o => o.Active == true).OrderBy(o => o.NAME),
                                 docown => docown.EMP_ID,
                                 EAL => EAL.EMP_ID,
                                 (docown, EAL) => new
                                 {
                                     NIK = docown.EMP_ID,
                                     Name = EAL.NAME,
                                     Dept = EAL.Organiz_Stru,
                                     EmailTo = docown.EmailAddressTo,
                                     EmailCC = docown.EmailAddressCC,
                                     EmailBCC = docown.EmailAddressBCC,
                                     ActiveEmp = EAL.Active
                                 }).ToList();

                            foreach (var obj in listObjName)
                            {
                                arrObj.Add(obj);
                            }
                    
                
                return arrObj;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return new ArrayList();
    }
```

Comment: without seeing any code it's pretty hard to hekp help you. Apart from this `ToList` doesn't return an `ArraList`, but a `List<T>`.

Comment: Could you provide more code? `query.toList()` will create a List out of your IEnumerable. `query.First()` gets you the first object of your query, `query.FirstOrDefault()` is also a possibility if you want a default if there is an empty query.
If you want to get a specific item out of your query you should use `query.Where().First()` and add your filter criteria into the Where method.

Comment: and where exactly do you try to access the arrays elements? Please be more specific on your issue.

Comment: @Yingrjimsch... yeeahh.. i figured out how to attach my code. and i already modified my question.. please help guys. thanks

Comment: @HimBromBeere ... yeeahh.. i figured out how to attach my code. and i already modified my question.. please help guys. thanks

Comment: @faridwahyu in my opinion you can get the value via `obj.Dept` and `obj.Name` but i think you already tried that. Is it possible for you to set a debug point at the line of your foreach and tell me how your `listDocOwn` looks like?
Also creating an ArrayList out of your List is really unnecessary

Comment: @Yingrjimsch.. yes you allright.. i have tried all of that.. and i tried to set debug, qiuck watch.. but i dont attain the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeeyy alhamdulillah...

by helping from my friend, I have figured out the solution. like below

```
foreach (var obj in listDocOwn)
        {
           var objDocOwnMod = new M_DC_DocumentOwnerModel()
                {
                    Name = (obj.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(obj)).ToString(),
                          Dept = (obj.GetType().GetProperty("Dept").GetValue(obj)).ToString()
               };
                listDocOwnModel.Add(objDocOwnMod);
        }
```

Comment: great if you found the solution. I wa thinking maybe if you are creating a `=> new MyClass` instead of `=> new ` the type is defined and you can get dept by `obj.Dept`
In my opinion the lack of typing leads to insufficient informations.

Comment: @Yingrjimsch .. actually, before i found this the solution.. i want to take out the classes in model folder.. and that classes can i use for customize query result which is not suitable with my entity context (DB first). if there is no solution for me. i will take this solution.